# XSLT - Put Content by checking attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT. and I've a xml to xml transformation task. what I have to do is put some xml node to result xml tree by checking some attribute values in original xml file.

example :

original xml has

```
<doc>
<sec id="sec_1" sec-type="scope"> </sec> 
<sec id="sec_1" sec-type="norm-refs"> </sec>
//more codes
<doc>
```

what I need to do is,put some new xml node (as example : 
`<c type="newaddingnode">&#x200B;</c>` ) at the end of the  node in to to the result xml by checking the attribute in  node

eg:

if `sec-type="norm-refs"` is exist insert the new node at the end of the `sec-type="scope"`. If this attribute does not exist, insert the new node at the end of the sec-type="scope". IF both sections are missing, do nothing.

so, if my original xml as follows,

```
<doc>
    <sec id="sec_1" sec-type="scope"> </sec> 
    //more codes
  <doc>
```

my result xml should be like this

```
<doc>
    <sec id="sec_1" sec-type="scope"> </sec> 
    <c type="newaddingnode">&#x200B;</c>
    //more codes
  <doc>
```

if my original xml as follows,

```
<doc>
    <sec id="sec_1" sec-type="norm-refs"> </sec> 
    //more codes
  <doc>
```

my result xml should be like this

```
<doc>
    <sec id="sec_1" sec-type="norm-refs"> </sec> 
    <c type="newaddingnode">&#x200B;</c>
    //more codes
  <doc>
```

and if both `<sec id="sec_1" sec-type="norm-refs">` and `<sec id="sec_1" sec-type="scope">` are not exist new node should not be added. also adding node should not be a child node of `<sec>`. but it should add end of the `<sec>` node.

in other languages this would be relatively easy task but I'm new to xslt, so I'm wondering how can I do this in XSLT. can I use `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:choose>` to do this ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused because you appear to want to insert the new node at the end of (presumably, as the last child of?) the sec with sec-type="scope" whether or not sec-type="norm-refs" exists. Is there a typo in your requirements statement? Showing specimen output for a couple of input cases would make it much clearer.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the comment. I edited the question as you requested. if you van go through it really appreciate .

Comment: Don't worry. This is relatively easy in XSLT too, once you know how. But what happens if both "scope" and "norm-refs" are present (in either order)? Where should the new node be added then? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC. Thanks for the comment. if both exist new node should go under "norm-refs". if "norm-ref" not exist and "scope" exist new node should go under "scope". if both not exist do nothing. there is another case. if "norm-ref" exist multiple time new node should go under each "norm-ref" node. My main concern is how do I use <xsl:if> or <xsl:choose> to address this matter. if you can prove so guidance I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think we still don't have a full specification, but I'll try. I think you've told us (a) add a new node after any sec with @sec_type='scope'. That's

```
<xsl:template match="sec[@sec_type='scope']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <c type="newaddingnode">&#x200B;</c>
</xsl:template>
```

(b) add a new node after any sec with @sec_type='norm-refs'. That's

```
<xsl:template match="sec[@sec_type='norm-refs']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <c type="newaddingnode">&#x200B;</c>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, there are other conditions that perhaps you haven't told us about, like what happens if both are present or if one of them is present twice. Those conditions can be handled by refining the match patterns or by adding more rules.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.:) the thing is if "norm-ref" exist new node should go under that node. this case do not concern about "scope".  if "norm-ref" not exist and "scope" exist new node should go under "scope" node. if both not exist do noting. there is another case. if "norm-ref" exist multiple time new node should go under each "norm-ref" node. My main concern is how do I use <xsl:if> or <xsl:choose> to address this matter. if you can prove so guidance I would be grateful.

Comment: I think my code does what you are describing. Your "main concern" should be to solve the problem, not to use particular XSLT instructions in your solution. If you see code with lots of xsl:if and xsl:choose instructions, it's generally written by someone who is inexperienced in XSLT and hasn't learnt that there are better ways of doing it.